# How to use angular2 pipe filter without ngModel but a simple string instead

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I've made an angular reusable pipe for filtering a list that's currently working with a input:text and ngModel ngModel tag

```
<input type="text" name="filterText" [(ngModel)]="filterText">
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let pais of paises | async | filter: filterText">
    {{pais.$key}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

But I need to use a static string instead of that dynamic ngModel variable

```
<li *ngFor="let pais of paises | async | filter: 'I NEED TO PASS A STRING IN HERE'">
```

How could I pass a string right after the colon?

Thanks you in advance! I'm still a noob at angular
Edit:

This is my pipe

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'filter'})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform{
transform(embajador:any, term: any): any{
    // check if search term is undefined
    if (term === undefined) return embajador;
    // return search
    return embajador.filter(function(embajador){
        return embajador.$key.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase());
    })
}
}
```

The data in paises is retrieved from firebase, this is what the object looks like

```
{
  "paises" : {
    "argentina" : {
      "active" : true,
      "location" : 0
    },
    "jamaica" : {
      "active" : true,
      "location" : 4
    }
  }
}
```

This is what my Homepage component lookslike

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2';
import {FilterPipe} from './filter.pipe'
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {
  paises: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public alertCtrl: AlertController, 
  af: AngularFire) {
  this.paises = af.database.list('/paises');
}

}
```

I'll also like to add that I'm working with Ionic 2 if that makes any difference

Comment: What you have there should work. [It's in the docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#chaining-pipes).

Comment: @Harangue I thought so but I'm getting "Cannot read property 'filter' of null"

Comment: @GerardoSabetta: can you please post code for your filter? Also please provide the data in paises variable.

Comment: @JayakrishnanGounder Sure just added what you asked for, thanks for trying to help!

Comment: @GerardoSabetta do you have some errors with `filter:'query'` ?

Comment: @yury.tolochko yes, as I replied to Harangue I'm getting "Cannot read property 'filter' of null" I can't find out why

Comment: Please add code where you're getting data from firebase. Is the `paises` object?

Comment: @GerardoSabetta This error throws from `return embajador.filter`. `embajador` is an object since you expect an array. I guess it would reasonable to create `object_to_array` pipe and place it before filter.

Comment: @yury.tolochko But why does it work with the ngModel input:text? I'll try, thanks in advance